# Spring Data JPA: Efficiently Query The Database for A Large Dataset

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have written an application to scrape a huge set of reviews. For each review i store the review itself Review_Table(User_Id, Trail_Id, Rating), the Username (Id, Username, UserLink) and the Trail which is build previously in the code (Id, ...60 other attributes)

```
 for(Element card: reviewCards){
                String userName = card.select("expression").text();
                String userLink = card.select("expression").attr("href");
                String userRatingString = card.select("expression").attr("aria-label");
                Double userRating;
                if(userRatingString.equals("NaN Stars")){
                    userRating = 0.0;
                }else {
                    userRating = Double.parseDouble(userRatingString.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", ""));
                }

                User u;
                Rating r;
                
                //probably this is the bottleneck
                if(userService.getByUserLink(userLink)!=null){

                    u = new User(userName, userLink, new HashSet<Rating>());

                    r = Rating.builder()
                            .user(u)
                            .userRating(userRating)
                            .trail(t)
                            .build();


                }else {

                    u = userService.getByUserLink(userLink);
                    r = Rating.builder()
                            .user(u)
                            .userRating(userRating)
                            .trail(t)
                            .build();
                }

                i = i +1;
                ratingSet.add(r);
                userSet.add(u);
            }

            saveToDb(userSet, t, link, ratingSet);
            savedEntities = savedEntities + 1;
            log.info(savedEntities + " Saved Entities");

        }
```

The code works fine for small-medium sized dataset but i encounter a huge bottleneck for larger datasets. Let's suppose i have 13K user entities already stored in the PostgresDB and another batch of 8500 reviews comes to be scraped, i have to check for every review if the user of that review is already stored. This is taking forever

1. I tried to define and index on the UserLink attribute in Postgres but the speed didn't improve at all
2. I tried to take and collect all the users stored in the Db inside a set and use the contains method to check if a particular user already exists in the set (in this way I thought I could bypass the database bottleneck of 8k write and read but in a risky way because if the users inside the db table were too much i would have encountered a memory overflow). The speed, again, didn't improve

At this point I don't have any other idea to improve this

Comment: 0. 13K rows is still a tiny DB. 1. You unnecessarily call userService.getByUserLink(userLink) twice if the user is found. 2. You pass entire userSet and ratingSet to saveToDb for each card process - while the code suggests you are saving only in each iteration - this is the most suspicious part for me. Is that necessary? 3. Processing in batches would reduce the number of calls.

Comment: @karalis1 Did the below answer help you? Do u need elaborating?

Comment: @karalis1 Please look at my update on the get part which i missed before..

Comment: Hey @Imk , thank you for your answer! I tried to implement a cache system, unfortunately Ignite couldn’t fully support my Java version so I tried with Redis but had some problem with Spring Cacheable annotation “#user.userLink” that wasn’t working properly. For what concern the query, your suggestion worked really well (Spring Data Projections). Your solution is overall on point and liked, I just need to try to master Redis to make it work perfectly

Comment: Ps: yes my if was inverted. I accidentally changed the != to == while trying to simplify my code in order to be posted here

Comment: Ps: i was already saving in bulk and also using saveAll() method to obtain the best performance. The problem was mainly on retrieving data

Comment: Cool...glad it helped! On Ignite we are using it..its much more than a simple distributed cache..so if you are thinking of adding Redis to your stack i would recommend considering using Ignite in its place (if you could resolve the java version issue that is) because Ignite is so much more feature rich than a simple distributed cache...you get more bang for the buck (adding a OSS to ur stack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for one, you would certainly benefit from not querying for each user individually in a loop. What you can do is query & cache for only the `UserLink` or `UserName` meaning get & cache the complete set of only one of them because that's what you seem to need to differentiate in the `if-else`.

You can actually query for individual fields with [Spring Data JPA @Query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) either directly or even with [Spring Data JPA Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) to query subset of fields if needed and cache & use them for the lookup. If you think the users could run into millions or billions then you could think of using a distributed cache like [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/use-cases/in-memory-cache.html) where your collection could scale easily.

Btw, the `if-else` seem to be inversed is it not?

Next you don't store each review individually which the above code appears to imply. You can write in batches. Also since you are using Postgres you can use [Postgres CopyManager](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html) provided by Postgres for bulk data transfer by using it with [Spring Data Custom repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations). So you can keep writing to a new text/csv file locally at a set schedule (every x minutes) and use this to write that batched text/csv to the table (after that x minutes) and remove the file. This would be really quick.

The other option is write a stored procedure that combines the above & invoke it again in a custom repository.

Please let me know which one you had like elaborated..

UPDATE (Jan 12 2022):

One other item i missed is when you querying for `UserLink` or `UserName` you can use a very efficient form of select query that Postgres supports instead of using an IN clause like below,

```
@Select("select u from user u where u.userLink = ANY('{:userLinks}'::varchar[])", nativeQuery = true)
List<Users> getUsersByLinks(@Param("userLinks") String[] userLinks);
```